# System.NullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net, nullpointerexception

Há um webservice que preciso criar cujo o mesmo precisa ter algumas particularidades, entre elas, a informação da SoapAction (conforme abaixo). Porém, quando coloco e vou debugar já recebo o erro ao testar o conteúdo da variável "orderID", retorna:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.' ==> confirmPaymentRequest was Nothing)

Quando eu tiro a SoapAction funciona, mas o cliente não consegue consumir porque retorna o seguinte erro:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: O servidor não reconheceu o valor do cabeçalho HTTP SOAPAction: confirmPayment.

Já não sei mais o que fazer, dada a pouquíssima experiência em ws.

Abaixo segue o método:

```
<WebMethod()>
    <SoapDocumentMethod(Action:="confirmPayment")>
    Public Function confirmPayment(ByVal confirmPaymentRequest As ps.confirmPaymentRequest) As ps.confirmPaymentResponse

        Dim retorno As New ps.confirmPaymentResponse()
        Dim orderID As String = confirmPaymentRequest.orderId
        Dim status As String = confirmPaymentRequest.status
        sql = "insert into ws_payment (orderid, status) values ('" & orderID & "','" & status & "')"
        txtExec = bco.exec(clsRetAcesso.acesso(homologacao, "dbWS"), sql)
        If txtExec <> "OK" Then
            retorno.success = False
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(LocalLog, Date.Now & " - 0030 - Erro: " & txtExec & vbNewLine & "SQL: " & sql & vbNewLine, True)
        Else
            retorno.success = True
        End If
        Return retorno
    End Function

'------------------------------------------------
'
```

Comment: O problema não está aí, está na chamada deste método.

Comment: Há outros webservices neste projeto que faço a chamada como neste exemplo e que não deram problema. Infelizmente, por não conhecer muito estou fazendo por tentativa e erro, mas não estou conseguindo.